# Hide content from template using cbv

Tags: python, django

I'm using standart django template sintaxis for hiding a part of content from template depends on user status. For example

```
{% if request.user.head_of_dept or request.user.seller or request.user.is_staff %}
```

I know how to use the dispatch function to restrict user rights, for example

```
class CustomCrudUserMixin():

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """Return 403 if flag is not set in a user profile. """
        if not request.user.head_of_dept or request.user.seller or request.user.is_staff:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Sometimes templates contain a lot of places where I have to use restrictions, I'm wondering if there's a way to redo the **dispatch** function so that don't have to use the syntax {} at the template?

Comment: You can use this mixin in your view that renders that template. You just don't need to do `class CustomCrudUserMixin()` you can only do `class CustomCrudUserMixin:`

Comment: Your question is unclear. How could the dispatch function know, or control, which parts of the template to hide?

Comment: @HigorRossato I think you misunderstood me, I need to make some of the content invisible

Comment: @DanielRoseman I just used dispath as an example, I want to know if there is any built-in functionality to hide content through view. If the answer is no, that's fine with me.

Comment: But the same comment applies. How can any method know what to hide if you don't mark it in some way?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that the perhaps easy way is to create a simple template tag and use that across all your templates.

```py
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='user_status')
def user_status(user):
    return any([user.head_of_dept, user.seller, user.is_staff])
```

Then on your templates you import and use this template tag passing the user to it.

```html
{% load user_status %}

{% if request.user|user_status %}
```

Comment: it's a good idea, but not exactly the answer to the question of whether it's possible to hide content through view

Comment: You're right. In that case, it'd be nice to see your `views.py` but I'd say that instead of "hide" you would "omit" content from your template.

Comment: I don't have a connection to a particular view or template. I want to understand whether it is possible to save myself from unnecessary work on writing in tens of places in the template conditions, in which part of the content will be visible or hidden. For example, if there are many EDIT buttons on a page, I need these buttons to be visible only to certain people. I have to add {% condicion %} before each button.